# Какие книги по nasm посоветуете?

Tags: ассемблер, книги, nasm, x86

(хз по теме или нет) изучаю nasm x86 и хотелось бы найти годную книгу (в которой будет и описание операторов, и как сделать некоторые алгоритмы, и как работать с памятью, короче все что только можно), так вот: что посоветуете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу посоветовать эту статью - https://codeby.net/threads/asm-obuchenie-2-ustanovka-po-i-pervaja-programma.68031/page-2 про nasm, автор рассказывает как установить среду разработки и написать собственную программу, а также рассказывает про базовый синтаксис сборки, который состоит из раздел данных, раздел bss, текстовый раздел.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).